# Aspect expression for method that implements interface with annotation on method

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I have

```
public interface MyInterface {
    @DoProfile
    void some();
}
```

and there're some classes that implement this interface.

I want to write an aspect (using Spring AOP) that will run around `some()` methods of all implementations of this interface.

Generally, I'd like to be able to mark any abstract or interface method with `@DoProfile` and have its implementations be wrapped with Around aspect.

Simple `@Around("@annotation(DoProfile)")` doesn't work. It works only when I put `@DoProfile` on concrete implementations. But I'd like to put `@DoProfile` to interface / abstract methods.

How to do that?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172673/pointcut-is-not-being-applied-to-abstract-method

Comment: this doesn't work as `@DoProfile` may be put to any method.

Comment: I just had a look around and found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178782/aspectj-pointcut-for-methods-that-override-an-interface-method-with-an-annotati

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulate annotation inheritance for interfaces and methods with AspectJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42607015/emulate-annotation-inheritance-for-interfaces-and-methods-with-aspectj)